Metallicity in super-metal-rich objects in the brown dwarf/red dwarf boundary
I am trying to make a red dwarf with twice the metallicity of the Sun. What could its theoretical minimum mass in Jupiter masses be?

VTC - this seems like a question for physics.stackexchange.com under the astrophysics tag.

Also VTC - but as an Avid Metalhead - I like the word Metallicity \m/
